# Wordpress 6.4 - How to select a different menu I have created?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

According to this tutorial for full site editing of a block theme, I should be able to see a list of navigation menus to select from.  Here is the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-l_InhV9cXs&t=161s) (see 3:33) and below is the screenshot from that video.  The dropdown menu clearly shows 4 menus available.

[image: wordpress 6.4 select menu]

I have created 3 menus.  Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Back on my Front Page, I have added want to add navigation.  If I do /nav... it inserts the first menu and there is no option to change the menu to one of the others I have made.  There is no pop up menu and so selection available in the main menu.  Here is a screen shot of the menu and bar at the top of the screen;

[image]

[image]

There is no way to select another menu;

[image]

Comment: question seems more appropriate here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ ?